# Alter data in a struct using solidity

Tags: solidity, remix, ethereum-wallet-dapp, solidity-0.6.x, solidity-0.8.x

I am trying to create a students record using remix
I am trying to replace data from an already stored struct.
How can I do that?
Below is my implementation untill now.

```
contract StudentContract  {


uint256 internal studentCount = 1;

// Struct to store data of users. 
struct StudentInfo {
string name;    
uint age;
string IdentityCard;
string FathersInitial;
string DateOfBirth;
string MailingAddress;
uint PhoneNumber;
string Country;
string Nationality; 


}

StudentInfo[] internal StudentInfoArray;
string[] internal OtherArray;
address payable public Owner;
mapping (address => uint256) internal students;


   constructor () {
    
    Owner = payable(msg.sender);        

}


event SetData(string message); 

function setData(string memory _name, uint _age, string memory _IdentityCard, string memory _FathersInitial, string memory _DateOfBirth, string memory _MailingAddress, uint _PhoneNumber, string memory _Country, string memory _Nationality) public returns (uint256) {
    
    require(students[msg.sender] == 0, "Data already exist for this wallet");
    
  StudentInfo memory tx1 = StudentInfo(_name, _age, _IdentityCard, _FathersInitial, _DateOfBirth, _MailingAddress, _PhoneNumber, _Country, _Nationality);
  StudentInfoArray.push(tx1);
  students[msg.sender] = studentCount;
  studentCount ++;
    
    
    emit SetData("Congratulations you have set your data");
    
    return studentCount;
    }
function ChangeStudentData(string memory _name, uint _age, string memory _IdentityCard, string memory _FathersInitial, string memory _DateOfBirth, string memory _MailingAddress, uint _PhoneNumber, string memory _Country, string memory _Nationality)public returns(bool success){
  students[studentCount].name;
  students[studentCount].age;
  students[studentCount].IdentityCard; 
  students[studentCount].FathersInitial;
  students[studentCount].DateOfBirth; 
  students[studentCount].MailingAddress;
  students[studentCount].PhoneNumber;
  students[studentCount].Country;
  students[studentCount].Nationality;
 return true;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, i have changed the code a little bit for you to understand easily;

First you have to reference the student you want to modify, then you can change the attributes of its struct.

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

contract StudentContract  {


uint256 internal studentCount = 0;

// Struct to store data of users. 
struct StudentInfo {
string name;  



}

StudentInfo[] internal StudentInfoArray;
string[] internal OtherArray;
address payable public Owner;
mapping (address => uint256) internal students;

event SetData(string message); 


constructor () {
    
    Owner = payable(msg.sender);        

}


function setData(string memory _name) public returns (uint256) {
    
    require(students[msg.sender] == 0, "Data already exist for this wallet");
    
    StudentInfo memory tx1 = StudentInfo(_name);
    StudentInfoArray.push(tx1);
    studentCount ++;
    students[msg.sender] = studentCount;
    
    emit SetData("Congratulations you have set your data");
    
    return studentCount;
}
    
function setNewName(string memory _name)public returns(bool success){
    uint studentId = students[msg.sender];
    StudentInfo storage newStudent = StudentInfoArray[studentId - 1];
    newStudent.name = _name;
    return true;
    
}

function getStudent(uint studentID) public view returns(StudentInfo memory) {
    return StudentInfoArray[studentID-1];
}
```

}